# php preg match \s modifier for multiple lines/spaces

Tags: php, regex

[Working code](https://regex101.com/r/1OZDHw/2)

But the amount of line breaks can be random,

```
<\/time>\s\s\s<a href=\"(.*?)\"
```

If the amount of lines/spaces are not known, in the example there are 3 line breaks so i entered 3 of them.

```
\s
```

What should I enter?

Comment: `\s*` should work, what's the problem?

Comment: Why doesn’t `\s*` work for you?

Comment: What about just using a parser? `\s*` would work as demonstrated here, https://regex101.com/r/1OZDHw/3.

Comment: The double quote (`"`) is not a meta-character in `regex`, it doesn't need to be escaped. If your `regex` uses `/`, use a different [delimiter](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) (f.e. `#`) and you can use `/` unescaped too.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
preg_match('/<\/time>\s{0,}<a href=\"(.*?)\" /', $value);
```

When I do this using curl to get a response from a web page one of the first things I do is run the response through a preg_replace and remove any extra spaces from the string.  Then you know that you will always be dealing with one space between any two characters.  Like this:

```
$value = preg_replace('/\s{1,}/', ' ', $value);
```